How to increase the size of the edges of the tree graph shown below to prevent overlapping
I am using the following code to plot R vines
bigpar(2,3)
junk<-fit.rv.sum.mle$RVM
junk[[7]]<-c("Roil" , "Rdollar", "Rbond", "Rgold", "Rcommo" , "Rsp1200", "Requity")
plot(junk,tree="ALL",edge.labels="family-tau",type=1)

I tried to change values in bigpar, tkplot, plot.igraph but nothing is helping. The whole R studio hangs if I make any change to the above code.
And the result I am getting has very small edges and overlapping nodes. How do I increase edge distance for a clear image.
Small edge graph
